# Xgboostの数学的背景について質問

Tags: 機械学習

XGboostの数学的背景について質問です。

Xgboostではロス関数の最小化の際に、
同関数をテイラー展開してから最適解を解くかと思います（Newton法）。

しかし、Newton法は、そもそも対象となる関数が2階微分できないと使用できない、
ヘッセ行列の正定値性が確保されないと使えないなどの欠点があったかと思います。
これについて同メソッドではどのようにクリアしているのでしょうか？

何卒ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願いいたします。